# Como desligar o PC em Assembly 16 bits no modo de boot

Tags: assembly, boot

Boa noite
Eu estou desenvolvendo um bootloader que grava num disquete. Consegui reiniciar já, mas não consigo fazer ele desligar. Já tentei vários códigos em assembly, mas nada funciona. Sempre ele trava e dispara o speaker dele infinitamente. Como posso fazer isso? Eu to no boot sem sistema operacional nenhum rodando. Obrigado

Comment: Pergunta interessante. Não sei a solução, mas uma breve pesquisa pelo SOEN e encontrei [isto](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21465186/1242661), pode ser que ajude no seu caso. Se conseguir resolver o problema, poste a sua solução, estou curioso.